# how to convert c# code to ironpython

Tags: c#, ironpython

[image]

From code I want to convert to ironpython

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not a language translation site. If you have encountered some particular difficulties when trying to solve the problem don't hesitate to ask. Nobody is going to do your job.

Comment: For brevity, I suggest using the `as` operator. This is a shorthand that is identical to `TryCast` i.e. `Fault f = response as Fault;` is equivalent to the first line of your method.

Answer (score 7):

**Copy and paste it into this site:** http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-python/

I would have done it for you and posted the result, but you posted an image instead of source code.
For shame.

Comment: Or http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx